# Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $g(x) = f(x + c)$. Then $g$ is measurable on $E - c$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm learning about measure theory and need some help with the following problem:

**True or False?**

Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. We define the function $g(x)$ as $g(x) = f(x + c)$. It follows that $g$ is measurable on $E - c$.

**My thoughts:**

The proposition is **true**. Since $f$ is measurable then the domain $E$ of $f$ is measurable by the definition of measurable functions. If we remove a point from the domain of $f$ the resulting set $E - c$ is still measurable so must be g.

---

Is my reasoning correct? Do I need to complete my proof with something else?

Comment: As Ahmed has pointed out, this is an unfortunate collision of notations. I would imagine that $E -c = \{ e-c| e \in E\}$ not $E \setminus \{c\}$.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $E - c$ is like a translation of the original set $E$ of $-c$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it must be  a translation. Otherwise there is no guarantee that $g$ is well defined (in terms of $f$).

Comment: You must establish conditions to the set $E$. First, $E$ should be a measure space, second, $E$ must allow translations. With the information you have provided we do not know what is $E$.

Comment: The problem doesn't state anything else. I think the conditions that $E$ is a measure space and translation invariant follows from the fact that $f$ is measurable. By the definition for measurable functions, $f$ is measurable if the domain $E$ is measurable.